# What is the corresponding OpenCV function of autocontrast in PIL?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I find there is a function of `ImageOps.autocontrast` in PIL, what is its corresponding function in OpenCV?

Edit:

I followed the docs of pil to implement one with `cv2` and `numpy`:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageOps, Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

def autocontrast(im, cutoff=0):
    channels = []
    for i in range(3):
        n_bins = 256
        hist = cv2.calcHist([im], [i], None, [n_bins], [0, n_bins])
        n = np.sum(hist)
        cut = cutoff * n // 100
        low = np.argwhere(np.cumsum(hist) > cut)
        low = low[0]
        high = np.argwhere(np.cumsum(hist[::-1]) > cut)
        high = n_bins - 1 - high[0]
        if high <= low:
            table = np.arange(n_bins)
        else:
            scale = (n_bins - 1) / (high - low)
            offset = -low * scale
            table = np.arange(n_bins) * scale + offset
            table[table < 0] = 0
            table[table > n_bins - 1] = n_bins - 1
        table = table.astype(np.uint8)
        channels.append(table[im[:, :, i]])
    out = cv2.merge(channels)
    return out

impth = './1_070323.jpg'
im = Image.open(impth)
imcv = cv2.imread(impth)
outcv = autocontrast(imcv, cutoff=10)[:, :, ::-1]
outpil = ImageOps.autocontrast(im, cutoff=10)
print(np.sum(outcv - np.array(outpil)))
```

Now I tested the speed of cv2/numpy and pil method, and I found that the cv2 method is even slower than pil method:

```
impth = './1_070323.jpg'
im = Image.open(impth)
imcv = cv2.imread(impth)
n_test = 100
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(n_test):
    outpil = ImageOps.autocontrast(im, cutoff=10)
t2 = time.time()
for i in range(n_test):
    outcv = autocontrast(imcv, cutoff=10)
t3 = time.time()

print('pil time: {}'.format(t2 - t1))
print('cv2 time: {}'.format(t3 - t2))
```

The result is that pil requires about 0.8 second while cv2 requires 3 seconds to run 100 times. I have read the source of pil implementation, it is full of python for-loops. How could it get faster than the cv2/numpy implementation?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no such a built-in function in OpenCV. You must implement it yourself. The Pillow documentation on [`ImageOps.autocontrast`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast) exactly tells you what to do. Implementing that using NumPy shouldn't be that difficult. Also, please notice, that generally [asking for resources, etc. is considered off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow (cf. your several questions now regarding "how to do this PIL stuff in OpenCV").

Comment: You can do that with Python Wand (based upon ImageMagick) using auto_level or contrast_stretch. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/wand/image.html or using (Python) Skimage exposure.rescale_intensity

Comment: See also OpenCV normalize with type=NORM_MINMAX at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd

Comment: I can make the cv2/numpy implementation work now, but the speed is slower than pil version, would you please tell me how I could make cv2 implementation as fast as pillow version?